# What exactly is the difference between Badges, Alerts, and Sounds?

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios

I specifically want to know what the difference is between badges and alerts in the Notifications options in the iPhone 4.

Could you provide screenshots of each case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Badges are the little numbered icons, like the one that appears on the Mail and SMS apps when you have new messages.

[image: iOS Badge example]

Alerts are popup messages like this:

[image: iOS Alert example]